# React updating specific object of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change a specific item of an object , which is contained by an array of objects, yet I cannot seem to find my mistake:

This is my formset array which contains the objects :

```
const [formset,setFormset]=React.useState([
        {
            id: uuidv4(),
            product:"",
            price: 0,
            quantity: 0,
            productSubtotal: 0,
        }
    ])
```

And this is how I am trying to change the `product` , for example:

```
const handleProduct = (e,id) => {

        setFormset(
        formset.map(item=>
            (item.id !== id? item : 
            {
        ...item , product: e.target.value
            })
        )
        )
    }
```

EDIT: The return statement from the parent component:

```
return (
        <div>
            {formset.map((item)=>{
                return(
                <PieChartGroupFormPresenter
                item={item}
                key={item.id}
                id={item.id}
                handleProduct={handleProduct}
                handleQuantity={handleQuantity} 
                purchaseList={purchaseList}
                product={item.product}
                quantity={item.quantity}/>
                )
            }
            )
            }
            <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>More</button>
        </div>
    )
```

The presenter component :

```
const PieChartGroupFormPresenter=({handleProduct,handleQuantity,product,quantity,item,purchaseList,id})=>{
    return (
        <div>
            <FormControl>
            <Select onChange={(id)=>handleProduct(id)} value={product}>
                {Object.keys(purchaseList).map((item,index) =>
                    <MenuItem value={item} key={index}>{item}</MenuItem>
                )}
            </Select>
            <TextField onChange={(id)=>handleQuantity(id)} value={quantity} />
            <TextField value={item.price} disabled>{item.price}</TextField>
            </FormControl>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have tried multiple variations of this approach yet none of them seem to work. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please describe what is the error or what is the exact nature of the issue?

Comment: Sure, when I actually try to change the input - if I start typing in the field - it doesn't start typing and my product doesn't get updated - yet it does rerender ...Also Maybe is worth mentioning that in my presenter component the onChange looks like this `onChange={(id)=>handleProduct(id)}`. Thanks !

Comment: @PeterMalik can you add the other parts of the code in order understand better what's happening? Maybe add also the presenter component.

Comment: @MarcoNisi  have just done it , hope its helpful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passing event as id, should be

```
onChange={(event)=>handleProduct(event, id)}
```

Same mistake for other field

```
//<TextField onChange={(id)=>handleQuantity(id)} value={quantity} />
<TextField onChange={(event)=>handleQuantity(event, id)} value={quantity} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleProduct = (e) => {
        setFormset({...formset,product: e.target.value})
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct, but thanks for your reply!

Comment: Please add a proper explanation to your answer and describe why this is the solution.